# How to add an annotation to the bottom of the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I want to make a note of my findings below the graph such as "Between 2000 and 2006 there was a 28% increase in cases."

I have tried using annotation_custom but in the case of facet_grid it puts it below each facet on the graph versus completely outside the graph area. I also tried to use grid-arrange from other searches on SO but no text even shows up anywhere that I can see.

```
library(ggplot2)
...
graph <- ggplot(data=dataSource, aes(x=factor(year), y=Cases, fill = type))
graph <- graph+geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_grid(.~type) 
graph <- graph+labs(title="Some title here", x="Year", y="Cases by county", fill="Type")
print(graph)
```

Comment: Code in SO questions should be reproducible. See [mcve].

Comment: in the github version of `ggplot2` there is a a new `caption` option in `labs()`

Answer (score 3):

Use `add_sub` in the cowplot package.  Here is the first example from the examples section of `help("add_sub")` :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
        geom_line(colour = "blue") + 
        background_grid(minor='none')
ggdraw(add_sub(p1, "This is an annotation.\nAnnotations can span multiple lines."))
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with `grid.arrange`

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(ggplot(), bottom = "annotation here")
```

[image]